# Add product description to BOM in odoo

Tags: odoo

Does anybody know how I can add the product description of every product added to a BOM in the manufacturing module. Basically what I want is that when I add an item to a BOM that its description is automatically added as well.

I have tried adding product.description but have had no luck.

Comment: could you plz help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876166/how-to-apply-a-default-calcul-to-the-list-price-field-product-odoo-v11

Answer (score 0):

change "description" field as a function/computation field such that it concatenates the products description of each bom lines to the bom object.

http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#computed-fields

Comment: Where exactly should I change the description field?

Comment: in mrp.bom, we have a field "description".  You need to change it to a function/computation field to add all the values of BOM lines.